# armv7 (32bit) only warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') w/ an expression of type 'NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-warnings

I had my code like this:

```
NSString *myString = [self fetchSomeStringWhichMyOrMayNotBeNil];

if (myString) {
    NSLog(@"yay, my string is not nil!);
}
```

then I changed (accidentally) into

```
BOOL myStringIsNotNil = myString;

if (myStringIsNotNil) {
     NSLog(@"yay, my string is not nil!);
}
```

This didn't throw a warning (`-Wint-conversion`) on 64bit devices, but it does on armv7 (32bit). I found out that a relevant difference is that `BOOL` is defined as `signed char` on 32bit and as `bool` on 64 bit.

But why doesn't it throw a warning on 64bit - and more important: how can I achieve a warning again?

Comment: Conversion to bool never throws a warning. The 32-bit implementation not having built-in booleans is in some sense broken.

Comment: Many warnings are not required to be diagnosed by the compiler anyways.

Comment: but which values does the `bool` contain then, is that clearly defined? And I really would like to have a warning then as it would be consistent throughout architectures.

Comment: You may enable a warning for any narrowing transforms but I think converting to bool is a special case (and for a good reason -- in if() many programmers exploit this).

Comment: bool is the type checked by if conditions, and it can be truth (true) or falsity (false). Anyway it's interesting only C++ guarantees a type distinct from the integral types.